# Why does Log4J2 look for config files with class loader strings in the filename?

Tags: java, classloader, embedded-resource, log4j2

I'm trying to set up Log4J2 and got its `StatusLogger` printing to the console so I could understand why it wasn't seeing my config file (for the curious, I think the problem was the JSON library Log4J2 uses wasn't in my classpath so it silently failed, but unfortunately I'm not certain).

However once I set the `StatusLogger` to print `TRACE` statements, I noticed something odd - it seems to be looking for resources with `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.toString()` calls in the filename, e.g. (newlines added for readability):

```
2013-12-09 01:07:23,938 TRACE Trying to find 
    [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] 
    using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
```

The file it's looking for is essentially `"log4j2"+classLoader+".json"` which struck me as odd.  But debugging through the config loading behavior, we see this stems from `ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext()` which does the following:

```
private LoggerContext locateContext(final ClassLoader loader, 
    final URI configLocation {
  final String name = loader.toString();
  ...
  LoggerContext ctx = new LoggerContext(name, null, configLocation);
  ...
}
```

Which eventually leads to `ctx.start()` being called, which ultimately calls `Loader.getResource()` passing in the value of `loader.toString()` as part of the `resource` string.  Looking at it, the behavior seems fairly intention, but I cannot imagine why it would be beneficial to be looking for such a resource name.  What does this get us?  Is this a bug?

---

SSCCE:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusConsoleListener;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger;

public class L4JTrace {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StatusConsoleListener listener = new StatusConsoleListener(Level.ALL);
    StatusLogger.getLogger().registerListener(listener);
    LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
  }
}
```

This should output something like:

```
2013-12-09 01:22:27,132 WARN Multiple logging implementations found: 
Factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, Weighting: 10
Using factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory
2013-12-09 01:22:27,148 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,160 DEBUG Found Plugin Map at jar:file:LOCALPATH
2013-12-09 01:22:27,162 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,202 WARN JmDNS or serviceInfo class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jmdns.JmDNS # Exception truncated
2013-12-09 01:22:27,221 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.062408180 seconds
2013-12-09 01:22:27,240 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2013-12-09 01:22:27,241 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT
2013-12-09 01:22:27,242 DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291
2013-12-09 01:22:27,242 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000013583 seconds
2013-12-09 01:22:27,245 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,245 DEBUG Missing dependencies for Json support
2013-12-09 01:22:27,245 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,245 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,246 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,246 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,246 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,246 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,246 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,247 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,248 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,249 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,249 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,249 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,249 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,249 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,250 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,250 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,250 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,250 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,250 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,251 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,252 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291 class loader.
2013-12-09 01:22:27,253 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2013-12-09 01:22:27,254 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,254 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000012075 seconds
2013-12-09 01:22:27,254 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2013-12-09 01:22:27,261 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000015998 seconds
2013-12-09 01:22:27,261 DEBUG Reconfiguration completed
2013-12-09 01:22:27,263 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-12-09 01:22:27,264 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have to do with web applications; multiple web applications can co-exist at the same time and need to have a separate LoggerContext. The ClassLoader object toString guarantees a unique name for the LoggerContext.

If you ask on the log4j Dev mailing list the log4j team members may be able to shed more light on this.